# How to write Python ElemenTree as XML File?

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

My Code

```
tree = ET.Element('e')
tree.attrib['u'] = 'F' + str(srh) + '_0'
if procedural_variables:
    pvs = ET.SubElement(tree, 'pvs')
    for procedural_variable in procedural_variables:
        pv = ET.SubElement(pvs, 'pv')

        n = ET.SubElement(pv, 'n')
        n.text = procedural_variable['name']

        v = ET.SubElement(pv, 'v')
        v.text = str(procedural_variable['value'])
ET.dump(tree)
```

How can I write this `tree` as some `file.xml`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like you should be able to use [`ET.tostring`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.tostring).  Alternatively, you could use the [`.write` method](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.ElementTree.write) of the `ElementTree` class

Answer (score 1):

```
file_out=open('output.xml','wb',1000)
ElementTree(file_out).write(tree,encoding="ASCII")
file_out.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Just recommend **lxml** to you. You can google it or click http://lxml.de.

It is pretty easy to use and robust! The API is rather close to that of ET, if not identical.